# how to access a member of struct that is a member of array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, function, struct

I have an Array called items1 its member's a struct Team1 with 2 members id: UUID() and round: Int I want to make a function that counts the sum of the round member of the array. can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong in my code below:

```
import Foundation

struct vrb {
    static var items1 = [
        Team1(id: UUID(), round: 14),
        Team1(id: UUID(), round: 20),
        Team1(id: UUID(), round: 24),
    ]

    static var total1: Int = 0
}

func Total() -> Int {
    var sum = vrb.items1[round.reduce(0, +)]
}

struct Team1: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var round: Int
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're somewhat close. What you're looking for is this:

```
func total() -> Int {
    vrb.items1.map(\.round).reduce(0, +)
}
```

Map ("transform each element of") `items1` to its `.round` values, and then sum those.

(Note that functions, methods, and variables should have a leading lowercase letter, and types like structs should have a leading uppercase letter. This makes it easier for other Swift developers to understand your code.)

Comment: one last question... how can I call the function inside the first struct vrb ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. There isn't actually a "struct vrb" here. You've created a static variable. That just creates a global variable that has a namespace. It's not clear where you mean "inside" in this case.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm kinda new into swift and programming in general also I'm a self taught so it's kinda not clear... I wanted to say the function won't work unless you call it and I want the function to do that calculation and show it later in a view

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer this question. It depends on what how you're using VRB, and what you are trying to do with it. I suspect you've made too many things `static` here (that's a somewhat more advanced tool; if you're just starting there are only a very small number of situations where you'd need `static`). I suggest opening a new question explaining what you're trying to do.

Comment: I do not know how I started using static but it somehow works... in my head static is used so you can use those variable outside of that struct... and I'm pretty sure it's not its job but it somehow works! I'm really new into swiftui and it's only my second or third project but I feel I'm moving forward... thanks for helping me